# Unable to unzip a downloaded file in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, zip, google-colaboratory, unzip

I've read dozens of questions about unzipping files from Google Colab. My question is different, you will read why.

I need to unzip a zip file on Google Colab in order to perform some computation on the images in it. The problem is that all the different utilities that I've used don't recognize the zip file as a zip file.

1. To avoid any problem in the creation of the zip file, I let Google Drive create one for me, simply selecting more than one image and clicking on download. Google Drive automatically creates a zip file containing the images. Let's call it `images.zip`
2. I re-upload `images.zip` on GDrive and share it copying its link
3. Then, in Google Colab, I download locally `images.zip`:

```
import urllib
import os

drive_url = 'the_link_to_the_zip_file'
file_name = 'images.zip'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(drive_url, file_name)

os.listdir()
```

Obtaining: `['.config', 'images.zip', 'drive', 'sample_data']`, so the file was successfully downloaded.

Now I would like to unzip it.

**Using zipfile**

```
import zipfile

zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("images.zip", "r")
zip_ref.extractall()
zip_ref.close()
```

The error that I get:

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-41-eca398f38f4a> in <module>()
----> 1 zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("xyz.zip", "r")
      2 zip_ref.extractall()
      3 zip_ref.close()

1 frames

/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
   1129         try:
   1130             if mode == 'r':
-> 1131                 self._RealGetContents()
   1132             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1133                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1196             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1197         if not endrec:
-> 1198             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1199         if self.debug > 1:
   1200             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

**Using unzip**

```
!unzip -uq "images.zip" -d "/content/drive/My Drive/Test"
```

The error that I get:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of images.zip or
        images.zip.zip, and cannot find images.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Obviously `images.zip` is a perfectly fine zip file, that I can open and modify both on my computer and online using Google Drive.

Note: I obtain the same result also uploading a zip file that I've created on my computer. Initially I was thinking that maybe my zip utility was broken, but now what it seems broken is Google Colab...

Note2: The solution isn't just access directly to the file images.zip in Drive and unzip from there because it could happen that I need to download locally a zip from someone else Drive

Many thanks

Comment: Please try this once and tell me if this worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61113374/13232994

Comment: hate to say it but I am seeing this same issue.  I have a valid ZIP file uploaded to github, I can download it directly from github and it unzips fine.  In Colab when I wget download it and try to unzip it I get the zip file showing in the folder but it breaks on unzipping with the same "End-of-central-directory signature not found" error.  If I then try and download that file to my local machine it wont unzip and is corrupted.  Upvoting this

Comment: I am going through the same issue and I'm not sure why but my zip file keeps getting corrupted when I try any of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got what the problem is. Looks like the file you are tying to extract is not a zip. Try this to verify if it is really a zipfile.

```
!apt install file
!file <location_of_zip_file>
```

I suspect that the file you downloaded is not zipfile because you might not have provided the direct URL to the file.

Comment: /content/qtrolley-training/zipfiles/2022-08-17.zip: ASCII text

Comment: I have the above as output, what should I do next?