# Unzipping image directory in Google Colab doesn't unzip entire contents

Tags: zip, google-colaboratory, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a directory of 75,000 images for training a CNN. When unzipping using,

```
!unzip -uq "/content/BDD_gt_8045.zip" -d "/content/drive/My Drive/Ground_Truth"
```

not all images unzip. I have about 5,000 I believe. I tried doing it several times but then I have some duplicates. Is there a limit to the number of images I can unzip?

I'm currently stuck on how else I'm meant to get all files into my drive to train the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colab's default 'unzip' binary doesn't work as expected. It seems to cancel the unzipping automatically after a few cycles. Run latest version of 7z and you are good to go.

```
# To extract with full paths
!7z x <filename.zip>

# To extract all the files in the same folder (ignore paths)
!7z e <filename.zip>

# To specify output directory, use '-o'
!7z x <filename.zip> -o '/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/FashionMNIST'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, I can't seem to find how to unzip it into a particular folder

Comment: You're welcome! I have updated the answer. Please consider upvoting the answer if it solved your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use 7zip instead

To extract to a specific folder type:

```
!7z x /content/path_to_folder/file.zip -o/content/path_to_destination
```

**Do not put space between -o and destination. Also no need for apostrophe('')**